# Why do I only get vehicle missions?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

The vehicle missions are the most boring ones and I keep having only some of these like "collect x times y", "break x times y", or "do x meters with y".

I got more than 30 vehicle missions in row and it does not seem very random.

At the beginning of the game it was not like that, what happened? How are the missions chosen? Is it because I have the gadget that makes me start with a free vehicle?

Comment: As of the last time I played (about a year ago), there were certain missions that were put in a random order, which then re-shuffles and repeats after you complete them all. It sounds like you've just got an unlucky order. Once you complete the vehicle missions, you should have few to none of them left until the mission cycle resets.

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack Joyride randomly generates the quests, so if you finish those eventually they'll run out, if that makes sense.

Comment: I've also been getting nothing but vehicle missions in the past month, and there are 3 deleted answers on this question saying the same thing. I think at this point you can't explain it with randomness.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had a curious month-long string of nothing but vehicle missions, [so I asked Halfbrick support about it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye0ky.png), and apparently it's a known issue.

> Thanks for your email and apologies for the inconvenience.
>
> This is a known issue which should be resolved in the next update.
>
> Thank you for your patience and understanding.

Nothing to do but wait, I guess.